# Internal error 500 on POST web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with my web api application. I get an internal error 500 when i try to post(save) a new user in my db.
The function bellow is the one that i use to make the client call.

```
public void InsertNewUser(RegisterModel pNewUser, string pEmail)
{
    // Build rest uri
    string lREST_Uri_Browse = string.Format(@"api/accountapi/saveuserdata"
    // User data
    /*pModelSerialized*/);

    // Complete URI
    string lREST_Uri = Helpers_API.endPoint + lREST_Uri_Browse;

    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Helpers_API.endPoint);

        var newUser = new Models.Models_API.Users
        {
            Email = pNewUser.Email,
            FName = pNewUser.FName,
            LName = pNewUser.LName,
            Inserted = DateTime.Now,
            ActiveAcc = true,
            AccType = pNewUser.AccType,
            BCompanyID = pNewUser.CompanyID,
            PID = pNewUser.PID,
            Password = pNewUser.Password,
            Token = GetToken(pEmail),
            ThirdParty = 0,
            Gender = pNewUser.Gender,
            BirthDate = pNewUser.BirthDate
        };

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        //    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        // Create the JSON formatter.
        MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

        // Use the JSON formatter to create the content of the request body.
        HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<Models.Models_API.Users>(newUser, jsonFormatter);

        var result = client.PostAsync(lREST_Uri_Browse, content).Result;
}
```

This is the model

```
public class Users
{
    public int BrokerID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Inserted { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public bool ActiveAcc { get; set; }
    public int BCompanyID { get; set; }
    public int PID { get; set; }
    public int AccType { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int ThirdParty { get; set; }
}
```

And bellow is the POST in APIController:

```
public HttpResponseMessage SaveUserData(Users pNewUser)
    {
        bool createUser = false;
        // First check for provided email in DB
        Users existingUser = asigCtx.Users.Where(u => u.Email == pNewUser.Email).SingleOrDefault();
        if (existingUser == null)
            createUser = true;
        else if (existingUser.ActiveAcc)
            createUser = true;

        if (createUser)
        {
            using (asigCtx = new AsigPrimeContext())
            {
                Users user = new Users()
                {
                    Email = pNewUser.Email,
                    FName = pNewUser.FName,
                    LName = pNewUser.LName,
                    Inserted = DateTime.Now,
                    ActiveAcc = true,
                    AccType = pNewUser.AccType,
                    BCompanyID = pNewUser.BCompanyID,
                    PID = pNewUser.PID,
                    Password = pNewUser.Password,
                    Token = pNewUser.Token,
                    ThirdParty = 0,
                    Gender = pNewUser.Gender,
                    BirthDate = pNewUser.BirthDate,
                };

                asigCtx.Users.Add(user);

                asigCtx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Users>(HttpStatusCode.Created, pNewUser);
        return response;
    }
```

Can anyone give me piece of advice with this code  because i'm new in this and i just want to do it wright. TNX

Comment: The funny thing is that in the post execution call when the code should receive as parameter the model sent from the client, this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your code.  A 500 error indicates that your code contains an unhandled exception that killed its worker process.

Change your web.config file so that your application outputs the full error message.

Comment: It's getting the error in the first part of the code because parameter "pNewUser" it's null...this is the problem, i get the null variable instead of the model that need to be saved.

Comment: Glad I could help you find the answer!

Comment: I already new this, sorry to disappoint you :)). My problem is how to send the parameter model trough the call so it could be used in the saving function from the api??

Answer (score 1):

A few things I would check/try to get to the bottom of the issue:

1. Is the code above exactly the same as in your application or have you changed anything (even if only to make it simpler)?
2. Is the `Users` object used in SaveUserData controller method definitely from the same assembly as the one that you are posting from the `InsertNewUser` method?
3. Is the `Users` object complete on the listing (e.g. does it have any constructors)?
4. Have you tried executing the request to the endpoint through fiddler? This way you take any potential bugs in the client call out of the equation to see if the controller method on its own works.
5. I've noticed this line:

   ```
   string lREST_Uri_Browse = string.Format(@"api/accountapi/saveuserdata"
   // User data
   /*pModelSerialized*/);
   ```

   Are you formatting the url and passing any params to it? If so, what are the params and what does your WebApi route look like?

That should be enough for a start - let me know how you get on.

BTW: Two things that strike me in your code (unrelated to the question):

- It's very confusing to have a class called 'Users' representing a single user. If it's you're code I'd advise to change that to singular.
- the properties on the `Users` object are using abbreviations - I don't think it's that expensive to spell them out and I can guarantee you that anyone new to this code will be grateful if you put a full name rather than a mysterious `BCompanyID`, or less mysterious but still hard to read (and write for that matter) `FName`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago. After doing a few tests, I've realized that my WebApi application was using DataContractJsonSerializer by default, instead of Newtonsoft. To fix it, you can change the default serializer on your server to NewtonSoft or to use DatacontractJsonSerializer to serialize your object and pass it to HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery to post some Json to the same  URL (`$.post(@"api/accountapi/saveuserdata", { Email: "e@example.com", FName = "Vlad" ... })`), thus eliminating `InsertNewUser` from the equation. If you still get a null `pNewUser` parameter in `SaveNewuser`, then I would look at your API's route configuration to make sure the server expects `SaveUserData(Users)`. If you get a non-null `pNewUser` from jQuery, then I would look closer at the output from `InsertNewUser`. If I had to bet, I would put my money on the routing configuration.

Comment: Routing have the default settings. Should it be something special?? The name of the controller is AccountAPI.

Comment: Did you try testing it with jQuery?

Comment: Also, I think posting a complex type to WebApi may need to hit a method that starts with "Post..." as shown [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) in the "Creating A Resource" section.

Answer (score 0):

it seemed that i had an error with the LINQ code

```
Users existingUser = asigCtx.Users.Where(u => u.Email == pNewUser.Email).SingleOrDefault();
```

After i solved this the request was ok.

Tnx for the help :) Appreciate.